# How do I automatically shutdown or pause my VirtualBox machine when I shutdown or restart my computer?

Tags: windows-7

When I shut my Windows 7 computer down or restart it (maybe because of Microsoft updates or installation of software or me just being stupid) **I want to automatically shutdown OR pause my VirtualBox machine just before it happens.**

Is there a way to do this?

My VirtualBox machine is running Linux, although I am hoping there is a solution which is guest-OS independent.

Comment: Hmm, scheduled tasks + python script to control VB, perhaps? http://blogs.sun.com/nike/entry/python_api_to_the_virtualbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtual Box has quite a bit of [command line arguments](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idp7138128) that can be used to create a small script to handle the pause. You can create a batch file to pause it and add it to the Task Scheduler or via Local Group Policy Editor  and have it triggered on shutdown.

Comment: thanks for that, I wasn't aware of *any* command line functionality for VirtualBox!